# Replacing document.write()s in an xhtml+xml page

Tags: javascript, xhtml, google-chrome, document.write

I work for a company that writes software which client sites embed with < script language="JavaScript" src=..... etc. etc. We depend quite a bit on document.write to write elements out to the page. One of our clients for some reason has opted to use the content-type "application/xhtml+xml", which makes document.write() unusable in chrome.

I understand why this is, and that DOM-compliant code should create each element, set its attributes, fill it with a text node if needed, attach the text node to its parent and the parent to some page element....

but what's a good workaround that doesn't require all this junk? The write()s therein have so many elements that the resulting code would be hideous if we made nodes and fastened them together like Knex or Legos or what-have-you.

edit: Tried using CDATA, but even this line is condemned similarly by the xhtml parser on the same page as our script embed:

```
<script language="text/javascript"><![CDATA[document.write('hi');]]></script>
```

Comment: At first glance, JSONML — http://jsonml.org/ — looks like it does what you want, but since I've just Googled it up and haven't spent too long looking at it, I'm not confident enough to call this an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = 'What you used to document.write()';
document.body.appendChild(el);
```

Note that you'll need to fix the HTML to be valid XHTML, but that should be much less work than converting all the code to use DOM manipulation.

Comment: It does it the html is valid xhtml. The code above is adapted from production code, and you'll find jQuery uses a similar technique for building fragments. Test page: http://pastebin.com/4akXVkv3

Comment: Okay, looks like it is implemented for all modern browsers and is part of HTML5. I'd bump up your answer but I'm locked unless you edit it.

Comment: Done, with a caveat added about the content needing to be valid xhtml.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can create an iframe of type `text/html`, write the content into that, and then import the nodes back into the main page.

Comment: +1 for a very creative idea, even though the accepted answer is probably simpler.

Comment: URL changed in frame will not show in browser, so the user can't add a specific page to bookmark

Answer (score 0):

We've been using Jquery and set timeouts to rewrite code supplied to us by similar organisations to yours. Here's an example from Search Ignite:

```
<script>
<!--
// once all the page has loaded
$(document).ready(function ()
    {
        // wait a bit so everything else that runs when the page has loaded loads, then...
        setTimeout(function ()
        {
            // ...load the tracking stuff
            var headerTag = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            var seo_tag = $.createElement(document.location.protocol + "//track.searchignite.com/si/CM/Tracking/ClickTracking.aspx?siclientid=123456&jscript=1", "script");
            headerTag.appendChild(seo_tag);

        }, 20);
    });
// -->
</script>
```

The timeout has the added benefit of making our page responsive to the user before the the external code has been loaded by the users browser, very useful if the external supplier's servers ever go down. Yes we loose some tracking stats but the user experience is not compromised.

Obviously you won't be able to rely on JQuery but you get the general idea.